# How to filter every row of the same character if one attend the condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following dataset `test`

```
> test = data.frame(location = c("here", "there", "here", "there", "where"), x = 1:5, y = c(6,7,8,6,10))
> test
  location x  y
1     here 1  6
2    there 2  7
3     here 3  8
4    there 4  6
5    where 5 10
```

Then, I want to make a condition where if `y` satisfy a condition, every location matched once are maintained in the dataset, something like

```
test %>% filter_something(y == 6)
  location x  y
1     here 1  6
2    there 2  7
3     here 3  8
4    there 4  6
```

Note that, even in line 4 there is no `y = 6`, they keep on the dataset, since there is at least one case where `location` match the 'right' `y`.

I can solve this problem creating another dataset using `y == 6`, and then doing an inner join with `test`, but any hint if there is another option more elegant?, because I'm not filtering just this variable, but I'm using another columns too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group_by` location, then use `any(condition)`

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% group_by(location) %>%
         filter(any(y==6))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to use data.table, we could first get the locations associated with y ==6, and filter on those, all in one line:

```
library(data.table)
test <- setDT(test)

# keep only the locations associated with y == 6
test <- test[location %in% test[y==6]$location]
```